# Should one study algebraic geometry if not interested in algebraic curves?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, soft-question, motivation

I'm currently enrolled in a fundamental mathematics program, where a lot of math is covered.

In particular, many of the students follow the Algebraic Geometry program, which is almost the core of the masters.

While I do enjoy category theory, homological algebra and algebraic topology I can't really understand the thrive for AG, as I'm not curious about algebraic curves (i.e the zeros of a polynomia of several variables on a given field), which is the fundamental object in AG. And I'm not that much filled with enthusiast with say Bezout's theorem. I'm also not much interested in Number Theory

However, I'm afraid of missing what is considered probably the most beautiful maths and its connections to fundamental physics, which look very appealing to me.

So if I'm not interested in the roots of AG, will I be interested in its further developments (presheaves, sheaves, schemes, topos ...) ?

Can I follow courses like "Introduction to schemes" without knowing anything in AG ?

Comment: My lack of expertise makes me too cautious to give this as an answer, but: Re: following an "introduction to schemes" class, I think you will need at least a basic knowledge of "classical" algebraic geometry: I'm not sure it's practical to approach a generalization of an object without already understanding the original object itself to some degree. That said, I'm not sure how much will really be necessary. 
As to the "should I be interested?" part, I'm not an expert (I'm *really* not an expert) (cont'd)

Comment: but my understanding is that algebraic geometry does have applications to category theory, algebraic topology, and homological algebra. See e.g. [this Mathoverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/25282/are-there-applications-of-algebraic-geometry-into-algebraic-topology) for a small list of connections with algebraic topology. [This other MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/77195/how-has-modern-algebraic-geometry-affected-other-areas-of-math) may also be of interest. (cont'd)

Comment: Meanwhile, [Johnstone's book on Stone spaces](https://www.amazon.com/Spaces-Cambridge-Studies-Advanced-Mathematics/dp/0521337798) could be considered relevant, insofar as one considers the various notions of "spectrum" treated within it to be part of algebraic geometry (this is admittedly a *really* broad interpretation of "algebraic geometry," but I'm not sure it's nonsense). I think that while it's difficult to make a normative claim here (one's life is finite and there are many areas of math out there), there is certainly ample *justification* to be interested in algebraic geometry.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have to confess my question is quite immature in its nature. The main reason why I fear missing something is because I do study in the school of Serre, Weil, Cartier .. (and country of Grothendieck) so there is some huge fascination for the subject, and the talks I listened to gave me the feeling there was something deeper in AG than in other stuff. (Kind of the impression I got while discovering Category Theory for instance).

Comment: You can certainly study schemes before learning classical algebraic geometry. A lot of people do this nowadays. There's a whole set of notes on that approach by Ravi Vakil here: http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/216blog/FOAGnov1817public.pdf

Comment: Indeed, one can study algebraic geometry without a specific look into curves. Then schemes and sheaves lie in the center of study. On the other hand, I like the theory of elliptic curves and their application to number theory and cryptography. This theory has developed a momentum on its own.